# How can I disable an attribute on a descendant selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to disable the border on my last anchor tag in my nav bar. I can get this working okay on other elements with only single selectors. How can I get this to work on a descendant selector?

```css
nav a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
}

nav a:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Music links</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nav a:last-child` will target all anchors that are the last child of their parents.

All your anchors *are* the last child of their <li> parents, so they're all targeted.

You should target the anchor of the last `li` instead, which you can do with `nav li:last-child a`.